# What do you call the guy who parks cars?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

What is the official name of the guy in the restaurant who takes the car from the customers and then returns the cars back to them when they finish visiting the restaurant?

"parking guy"?

Comment: For future one-word problems, you may want to use a [reverse dictionary.](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=person+who+parks+cars+in+restaurants)

Comment: Of course we call him Peter Parker, or maybe Richard Parker.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The term is *valet.*

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valet_parking) has a whole page on it. Though I could not find a clear definition in any dictionary, a paragraph from the Wikipedia page says it all.

> Valet parking is a parking service offered by some restaurants, stores, and other businesses, particularly in North America. In contrast to "self-parking", where customers find a parking space on their own, customers' vehicles are parked for them by a person called **a valet.**

Down there on the page:

> parking valet – a service employee who parks cars for guests, only from 1960.

Things apart, as J.R. describes (Thanks J.R.), it's better to say - *The valet parks the car for the customer*. If you still want to use *receive*, you may say *The valet receives an order of parking a car from its owner.*

Apart from that, there are professional services as well. They are defined as *[car valeting services](http://www.carvaletuk.co.uk/).*

Comment: Thanks, please do we say `the valet takes the car from the customer` or `the valet receives the car from the customer` or another word than `takes` and `receives` ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: Either would be correct, although "receive" sounds more polite than "take".

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli - I wouldn't say either one of those. I'd simply say, "The valet parks the car for the customer." Since the customer retains ownership of the car, there's really no "taking" or "receiving." You could also say, "The customer leaves the car for the valet."

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Yes, J.R. is correct but then a valet can *receive/take* an order of parking the car by the owner. However, in any case, J.R.'s version is better.

Answer (score 2):

A 'Valet' is a person who takes a customer's car (in your case, a restaurant).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valet_parking

Comment: Thanks, please do we say `the valet takes the car from the customer` or `the valet receives the car from the customer` or another word than `takes` and `receives` ?

Comment: `The valet takes the car from the customer.` is good. You may be able to say `The valet parks the car for the customer`, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

**Valet Attendant** is the word I would use. In fact, I'd bet on this term having a larger frequency of concordances in newer corpora.